# Overcoming 255 character URI limit for files_managed

Tags: 7, files, uri

I recently stumbled upon an interesting limitation of Drupal. It seems that in the table files_managed there is a field called "uri" which represents the path to the files being managed by Drupal. This field is defined as a VARCHAR(255). I was blissfully ignorant of this fact/limitation until one of our users initiated a chain of events that lead to Drupal trying to manage a file with a 261 character path, at this point Drupal gave a nasty database error which lead me to this issue.

Is there anyway to configure Drupal to allow file paths longer then 255 characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can alter the database defined from another module, but this is generally a bad idea. As said from Letharion, it is probable you are going to cause issues with other modules that take assumptions.

If you really need to do it, then you should implement code that (at least):

- Alters the database table defined from the other module
- Implements [hook_schema_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7) to make other functions know the new schema used for the database table

The latter step is necessary because there are functions, such as [drupal_write_record()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7), that use [drupal_get_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_schema/7), which invokes `hook_schema()`, and `hook_schema_alter()` to know the schema used for a table.

Your code should be at least the following one.

#### mymodule.install

```
function mymodule_install() {
  if (db_table_exists('file_managed') && db_field_exists('file_managed', 'uri')) {
    $schema = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed('system');
    $schema['file_managed']['uri']['type'] = 'varchar';
    $schema['file_managed']['uri']['length'] = 12288;
    db_drop_unique_key('file_managed', 'uri');
    db_change_field('file_managed', 'uri', 'uri', $schema['file_managed']['uri']);
    db_add_unique_key('file_managed', 'uri', array('uri'));
  }
}

function mymodule_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  if (isset($schema['file_managed']['uri'])) {
    $schema['file_managed']['uri']['type'] = 'varchar';
    $schema['file_managed']['uri']['length'] = 12288;
  }
}
```

What is missing in the code I shown is the code to unistall the module. It should change the database table as it was before the module was installed, but what happens if another module installed after yours alters the same field in that table?

Notice that, generally, managed files have a URI that is similar to public://field/image/100_0140.JPG. If the problem is the path being too long, then you should use less directories, or a shorter filename.

Comment: I have  the same problem. Using  Drupal  9.x and from what  I can  see db_* procedural functions of the Database API layer have been deprecated.  https://www.drupal.org/node/2993033. Same  also for  drupal_get_schema_unprocessed.

Comment: Most of these seem to have replacements e.g. \Drupal::database()->schema()->tableExists('file_managed') for db_table_exists('file_managed'). drupal_get_schema_unprocessed looks like it has been replaced by drupal_get_module_schema($module, $table);  however that has itself been deprecated with no replacement afaict. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21schema.inc/function/drupal_get_module_schema/9.2.x

Comment: @Daniel Those are replacements for Drupal 8; Drupal 7 still uses the functions I listed in this answer.

Comment: ok, I think I have figured it out. I have created a small module to help with this in d8+ https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_process_html/

Answer (score 1):

You can't configure Drupal to allow longer file names because the schema is hardcoded.

However, trying to upload a file with a longer file name shouldn't lead to a database error, you should report that as a bug report against the module that allowed to upload/create such a file.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider Berdirs answer the correct one, but I want to add that there *is* a [hook_schema_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7), which *can* allow you to make this change.

Most of the time though, it's not a good idea, simply because it's so rare that you are likely to hit other issues from modules making assumptions you've rendered false.